# Django sessions don't work with Apache installed on Ubuntu

Tags: django, apache, session, ubuntu

In production server I can't login to my website.
I know that it is some bug of Django with MD5 crypt or something like that, but unfortunately I don't remember what I should do. I am searching the answer since half day, but I can't find this website where was explained this problem.

DO you know how I can do sessions working.

Comment: Does everything work fine for you when you go through runserver?

Comment: yes, in runserver all is ok, I think that I have this page:
http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ModPython#MD5Issues
I will check it is working.

Comment: Sorry, but problems is otherwise. I am using subdomains like pl.domain and uk.domain and domain. User is only logged in one subdomain, but I want make it logged in all website. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In answer to this bit the comments

> Sorry, but problems is otherwise. I
>   am using subdomains like pl.domain and
>   uk.domain and domain. User is only
>   logged in one subdomain, but I want
>   make it logged in all website. Is it
>   possible? – Thomas

you need to allow cross-domain sessions that don't just refer to a subdomain. By default, Django will give you different sessions for bar.example.com and foo.example.com.

In your settings.py set [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) to .domain.tld (don't forget the leading dot!) and you'll be sorted.